# Get all mysql selected rows into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am wondering if there a function in php that can allow me put all my selected data in an array .Currently i am using mysql_fetch_array and as i have read in the manual,that function won't fetch every record in the table.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");            
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Those `mysql_...` functions are old and unsafe. You should used `mysqli` or better PDOs - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php, http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: As Raeki said, mysql are quite old, but other than that, if you still want to loop trough the result, you can do it with following code:
`$allRows = array(); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {$allRows[] = $row }`

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: In case you're copy/pasting, toske needs to add a closing `)` for his while. `$allRows = array(); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {$allRows[] = $row }`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I would suggest the use of MySQLi or MySQL PDO for performance and security purposes, but to answer the question:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

If you switched to MySQLi you could do:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json );
```

Comment: Thanks, after so many years this answer finally set me free with the truth

Comment: Glad that almost 10 years later and there's still value in this answer!

Comment: Straight for solution..! :)

Answer (score 11):

1. Loop through the results and place each one in an array
2. use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get them all at one time

Answer (score 8):

**You could try:**

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($rows, $row);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$name=array(); 
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $name[]=array('Id'=>$result['id']); 
    // here you want to fetch all 
    // records from table like this. 
    // then you should get the array 
    // from all rows into one array 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is also very nice, you can try it.

```
 try {
       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        array_push($row...);           
    }    
} catch (Exception $e) {
     print($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call mysql_fetch_array() for no_of_row time