# How to get numbers of line with sql?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli

How can I get the numbers of the lines where userid=8.
I have a table with cloumns like ID and userid.
So I am trying to put in php array the numbers of the lines that userid=8.

exmple:

- I have lines 1-10, and userid=8 at lines: 1,4,7,10.
- $counter[1] = 1
- $counter[2] = 4
- $counter[3] = 7
- $counter[4] = 10

[image: Table image]

I tried to use this answer: [Get all mysql selected rows into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264395/get-all-mysql-selected-rows-into-an-array) but its didnt work.

This is how I am getting the lines where userid=8 , but how can I put them into array?

```
$midSelect[i]="SELECT * FROM times WHERE userid=8;
$midResult[i]=mysqli_query($con,$midSelect[i]); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($midResult[i])) {
$mid[i]=$row['id'];
}
```

Comment: You can just use column `id`

Comment: @Fabio ok but how can I put in array the ids where userid=8?

Comment: `SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE userid = 8`

Comment: Is your problem in the database logic or in actually talking to the database at all?

Comment: Show us your code about fetching data from database, we can help with that

Comment: @WilliamIsted you didnt understand me, I want to take the IDs, where userid=8. But I want to save them in array. how can I do that?

Comment: @jycr753 I am still working on the system, no one uses it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just one step away from do it

```
$sql ="SELECT id FROM times WHERE userid=8";
$query =mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

$mid = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $mid[] = $row['id'];
}

print_r($mid);
```

Your required values are now stord in your array `$mid`

Upon op request i add some code

Now if you need to `echo` values you can loop in the array and print while iterating

```
foreach($mid as $val)
{
    echo $val . '<br />';
}
//print 
// 1
// 4 
// 5
// 8
```

Comment: Actually I am new in php so this is the first time I see print_r.. How can I change it to normal array or at least use it?

Comment: You can't echo an array, you can either orint using scopes `echo $mid[0]; echo $mid[1];` and so on or loop in the array and echo variables while iterating

Comment: Ok I got it! One moment I will suggest you edit thats doing it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `times` WHERE `userid` = '8'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);    

$loopcounter = 0;

/* associative array */
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $loopcounter++;
    $counter[$loopcounter] = $row['id'];
}

/* print counter */
print_r($counter);

/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Ok I will try, one moment :)

Comment: how can I print the variables from the array?

Comment: print_r($counter); ... updated my answer, please check the updated code

Comment: $loopcounter variable is not really needed

Comment: @Fabio It is required... please see the question. He wants the array index to start from 1

Comment: Array does put number from 0 to x according with how many items you put by itself, as i said it's not really needed

Comment: Array starts its index from 0. So in order to start the index from 1, we need to explicitly give the index. Therefore it is required. If we omit it, it will start index from 0. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok got it. I don't think he really needs to start from 1 though