# Addition with several SQL results

Tags: php, mysql

I got following sql statement:

```
 $sql4 = "SELECT 
          customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity,
          products.products_price
        From
          products Inner Join
          products_description
            On products.products_id = products_description.products_id Inner Join
          customers_basket On customers_basket.products_id = products.products_id
        Where
          products_description.language_id = '".$lang."' And
          customers_basket.customers_id = '".$cid."'";
```

Now the thing is before the sql query is made i don't know how many results it will have. What i need to do first after i got the query done is:

```
customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity * products.products_price
```

Then i need to make an addition. So the calculation above happens for every row itself. Then i need to add all the results with each other so i get the total price at the end. How would i do that in my PHP or even in MySql?

I read this thread [Get all mysql selected rows into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264395/get-all-mysql-selected-rows-into-an-array) but it didn't help me out.

**EDIT**

To be more precise:

For example my query gives me following result:

```
customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity | products.products_price 
2                                            5
3                                            4
```

Now i need to do following:

```
2 * 5 = 10 
3 * 4 = 12 

10 + 12 = 22
```

Comment: change select to this `Select sum(customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity *          products.products_price)`  assuming you just want the result 22 and assuming you will always be looking at a specific customers_ID basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can update your query like this:

```
$sql4 = "SELECT customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity, products.products_price,
          (customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity * products.products_price) as total, (select sum(customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity * products.products_price) from products products  Inner Join
      customers_basket On customers_basket.products_id = products.products_id ) as total_sum
        From
          products Inner Join
          products_description
            On products.products_id = products_description.products_id Inner Join
          customers_basket On customers_basket.products_id = products.products_id
        Where
          products_description.language_id = '".$lang."' And
          customers_basket.customers_id = '".$cid."'";
```

also you can make summation with php when you loop you result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM`:

```
    "SELECT 
          SUM(customers_basket.customers_basket_quantity * products.products_price) as total
        From
          products Inner Join
          products_description
            On products.products_id = products_description.products_id Inner Join
          customers_basket On customers_basket.products_id = products.products_id
        Where
          products_description.language_id = '".$lang."' And
          customers_basket.customers_id = '".$cid."'";
```