# How to access a specific row's column values from a fetched array, without looping

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a table of news items (with fields title, content, date, source & a primary index). With `$newsrow['title']` I have successfully managed to fetch the title for the first row item, but thereafter cannot access items for the next row. I tried `$newsrow[#]['title']` (by which I mean $newsrow[0]['title'] to access the first row's title), but that flags: `Warning: Illegal string offset`. Would avoid using a loop here because there are some exceptions within and i think there could be a more direct way here.

Following is the function I am calling (newfunction.php):

```
<?php     
     function news_data($conn)
  {         
      $query  = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER by newstrack ASC LIMIT 3";
      $result = $conn->query($query);
      $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);         
      return $row;      
  }       
 ?>
```

This is how I'm accessing the value in the front end:

```
<div class="art1">
                    <h4 class="newshead"><?php echo $newsrow[0]['title'];?></h4><br>
                    <img src="images/jaipur2.png" class="pic1">
                    <p class="newspara">Sessions unfolded at a charming colonial heritage property. Among the guests were ...</p><br>   
                </div>

                    <img class="tab3" src="images/newstab.png" alt="main">  
                    <a href="reviews.html">news</a>
<div class="art2">
                    <h4 class="newshead"><?php echo $newsrow['title'];?></h4><br>
                    <img src="images/aksh.png" class="pic2"> 
                    <p class="newspara">From a trip to the temple to a meeting with students </p>           
                </div>  
                <div class="art3"><br>  
                    <h4 class="newshead">FEST A HIT WITH VISITORS</h4><br>
                    <img src="images/kumaon.png" class="pic3">
                    <p class="newspara">The first edition of the two-day Food Festival kicked off <b>...</b></p>    
                </div>
        </section>
```

My setup makes the connection and also passes the above function to an array variable:

```
$newsrow = news_data($conn);
```

And for completion, here is the table structure:
[image]

Would appreciate any light on how to access values of specific rows, without looping.

Comment: Do me a favor and do `var_dump($row);` please.

Comment: It throws out details of only the first row: `array(16) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["newstrack"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(44) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> (PHP 5, PHP 7) mysqli_result::fetch_array -- mysqli_fetch_array —
>   Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both

This returns only one row, not all the rows as I suspect you're looking for.

Perhaps have a look at this [Get all mysql selected rows into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264395/get-all-mysql-selected-rows-into-an-array) if you wish to return all rows in one array. The given answer there is (you don't need the json_encode)

```
$json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json );
```

Comment: Didn't know `fetch_array` returned only a single row, thanks for the link, am now using  `$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and it works with fetching the values of the specific columns of the specific rows, as I had intended. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function `fetch` returns the next row from the pointer (so the first call returns the first row, the second the second and so on). This is why you get an error while trying to access with `$newsrow[#]['title']`. You are actually accessing the column 0 of the result.

To answer your question: You can move the pointer with data_seek (http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.data-seek.php). Which would lead to:

```
$result->data_seek(#);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't know it returned only a single row, thanks for the link, am now using  `$row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` and it works with fetching the values of the specific columns of the specific rows, as I had intended. thanks.