# Fetch all records into a variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I have table: TableA

```
id | name
------------
1  | joe
------------
2  | Mike
------------
3  | Andrew
------------
```

Now I know how to fetch records from TableA

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from TableA");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
  \\execute code;
}
```

But I would like to know that there is another way to fetch records without using while loop?

Means:

```
$row=array();
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql); //Assume here that it gives all record in $row.
```

Fetch all records in $row. So that we can use $row for later use throughout the script whenever we want again and again

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$results = mysqli_fetch_all ($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This other answer might also give you some clues:

[Get all mysql selected rows into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264395/get-all-mysql-selected-rows-into-an-array)