# How to retrieve all data from mysql database using php?

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, wampserver

I have a another php file that has the function to connect to the database (does so successfully) and also a function getEvent that contains the sql statement. 
The code below successfully retrieves one data row from the database but i need it to return all data from the table.

```
<?php
// include db connect class
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_Functions();

 // array for JSON response
$response = array();

// get all events from events table
$event = $db->getEvent();

// check for empty result
if($event !=FALSE){


    $response["error"]=FALSE;
    $response["uuid"] = $event["eventID"];
        $response["eventdetails"]["title"] = $event["title"]; 

echo json_encode($response);

}else{
$response["error"]=TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "No events to display";
        echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

the getEvent method

```
public function getEvent(){ 
    $stmt= $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from eventdetails"); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $event= $stmt->store_result(); 
    if ($stmt->execute()) { 
        $event = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc(); 
        $stmt->close(); 
        return $event; 
    } else { 
        // events dont existed 
        $stmt->close(); 
        return null; 
    }
```

Comment: Your comment "get all events from events table" doesn't seem to be correct since that function appears to only return a single event. It looks like you need to make a function in `DB_Functions` that gets all the events as an array.

Comment: Could you gave me an example of how to return the data as an array? This is the function i am using at the minute.  public function getEvent(){
 
  $stmt= $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from eventdetails");
  $stmt->execute();
       $event= $stmt->store_result();
 if ($stmt->execute()) {
          $event = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();
 
            return $event;
        } else {
            // events dont existed
            $stmt->close();
            return null;
        }

Comment: That's pretty difficult since you haven't posted any of your database code. I don't even know if you are using mysqli or PDO and whether it's the procedural or object oriented interface assuming it's mysqli. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11264436) might be able to help somewhat though.

Comment: A bit of inteligent code indentation would do no harm!

Comment: Organise your thoughts in the `getEvents()` method. It looks like you have tried almost everything other than the obvious

Answer (score 0):

If youwant to return an array containing all the results from a query then use the `fetchAll()` method of the PDOStatement Class

```
public function getEvent(){ 

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from eventdetails"); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $events = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
    return $events;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the fetchall() method, when i use it i get an error stating Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll().