# Sending push notification to multiple device on click

Tags: php, push-notification

I am building an application which needs to send alerts to multiple users on click. However currently I am only able to push to one device when i run the url. I did this with the tutorial from

> https://phonegappro.com/tutorials/apache-cordova-phonegap-push-notification-tutorial-part-3/

I have also added 'regids' in my user table in database and I got it working that once users login their regids will be automatically stored to the database. So now I need to call out regids for users selected and send push notification to them. How do I make changes to my current php in order to do so? Also, I need to make the `title = user's username` instead of hard coding it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```
<?php
require 'connecting.php';

$to= $result;
$title="SiQi:";
$message="Are you safe?";
sendPush($to,$title,$message);

function sendPush($to,$title,$message)
{
// API access key from Google API's Console
// replace API
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyAToG8Xw3g6PbpM55-ZmTckLebGsYUGLns');
$registrationIds = array($to);
$msg = array
(
'message' => $message,
'title' => $title,
'vibrate' => 1,
'sound' => 1


// you can also add images, additionalData
);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT regids FROM user");  
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);

$fields = array
(
'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
'data' => $msg
);
$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
}
?>
```

The result from php:
[{"regids":"eKZu8R9f3lQ:APA91bH8hL8Mi1-CizwW3Gir2tQ-Ojx6GoBmYPmnPtZv6z_jf_HO27KJQX1YQSHV6Z7Av8ievbtU8VOgtJVMVj0D5AeRmRuUmNhSYKQ-cU4mbbJt-_2E0SqT4xda3WcCumCYKd6uxqIy"},{"regids":"c5JsjAL-gQ4:APA91bF0XmzjD7D2UpcHpNpsUU-kw911yCymga792n19ZtI5QfA3schZQ3Do9ZO5UUwktyCa3SMNmcdH5G1EBsERZ-6vwFNWzXLB7Y0MxQvA54slfXm-QgNjWL-RftlYYXQvdIhmTjtx"}]{"multicast_id":7092212693151815966,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Comment: you can migrate your gcm to fcm and use topic subscribe to send notification to all devices\

Comment: will the codes be different in my html pages?

Comment: i think you can check firebase migration docs. and if you want to use gcm then in your code put all tokens from database so all devices get notification

Comment: Yeah but how do I do that? I know i need to modify the $to to all the regids in my database where userid = userid selected in the application but I'm not sure how to change my php in order to do that

Comment: fetch all tokens from your database and then put them in array and 'registration_ids' => $registrationIds;   here $registrationIds is array of tokens\

Comment: sorry but could you type out the codes for me? I'm not sure on the way to modify. $to = $query = "SELECT regids FROM user";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    // set array
    $registrationIds = array(); so i just add this line? is this correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264395/get-all-mysql-selected-rows-into-an-array

Comment: I tried changing but now my php got error

Comment: which error????

Comment: The result from php: [{"regids":"eKZu8R9f3lQ:APA91bH8hL8Mi1-CizwW3Gir2tQ-Ojx6GoBmYPmnPtZv6z_jf_HO27KJQX1YQSHV6Z7Av8ievbtU8VOgtJVMVj0D5AeRmRuUmNhSYKQ-cU4mbbJt-_2E0SqT4xda3WcCumCYKd6uxqIy"},{"regids":"c5JsjAL-gQ4:APA91bF0XmzjD7D2UpcHpNpsUU-kw911yCymga792n19ZtI5QfA3schZQ3Do9ZO5UUwktyCa3SMNmcdH5G1EBsERZ-6vwFNWzXLB7Y0MxQvA54slfXm-QgNjWL-RftlYYXQvdIhmTjtx"}]{"multicast_id":7092212693151815966,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Comment: check your server key and try to send specific token and check that device get notification or not.

Comment: It works when I specify just one regid to send to a single device. But I'm trying to send to multiple device now

Comment: Then your array format is not valid, Check other post about array format for fcm

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Firebase Cloud Messaging**

FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure to make sure we continue to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.

The new FCM SDK:

1. Simplifies client development. You no longer have to write your own
   registration or subscription retry logic.
2. Enables a new serverless notifications solution with a web console,
   Firebase Notifications. With Firebase Notifications, anyone can send
       notifications to target specific audiences based on Firebase
       Analytics insights. They can then evaluate notification
       effectiveness by assessing the built-in Notifications Funnel
       Analysis in the console.

Also FCM is more easy to use.

**You can send messages to**

1. single devices
2. groups of devices
3. devices subscribed to topics

**Try**

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client
2. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

Also you can use your own app server

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting. I've read https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-tutorial-using-firebase/ and the codes is different from what I need as I'm building my application on HTML5, something similar to here https://phonegappro.com/tutorials/apache-cordova-phonegap-push-notification-tutorial-part-2/